# Using Jquery and $(this).text() to replace th text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying append a two digit year to a column header that is autogenerated for me. It seems like a simple problem.  I have this table

```
<table border="1" id="Datatable1">
<tr>
    <th>Jan-</th>
    <th>Feb-</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>January's data</td>
    <td>February's data</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and this jquery

```
$(document).ready(

function () {
        var TwoDigitYear = '14';

    $('#DataTable1 th').each(function () {
        var curtext = $(this).text();
        if (curtext != "") {
            var newtext = curtext + TwoDigitYear;
            $(this).text(newtext);
        }
    });
}

);
```

For some reason, I can see the value changed if I put a console.log in the code, but the web page doesn't change.

Here's a jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/PasadenaJacket/Ztnvr/#base

Comment: You have `id="Datatable1"` but your code tries to use `DataTable1` Also, your fiddle doesn't include jQuery, so that doesn't work either

Comment: [Fixed your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ztnvr/3/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `DataTable1` you need to do `Datatable1` then it should work.

[**See UPDATED FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bXVRS/)

Comment: Vote to close as typo then, please.

Comment: Vote for close needed?? @JanDvorak

Comment: Typo questions are not useful for this site and should be closed. People who find this question through google aren't going to have their problem due such typo.

Comment: Thanks all for catching the typo.  Sorry for the submission.